# Sumar fills de tablas en R

Tags: r, tablas

Soy muy nuevo en R, y estoy atrapado en un problema que seguramente tenga una fácil solución.
Digamos que tengo 3 columnas en una base de datos:

| Color de la flor | Especie de insecto que la visita | Nº insectos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blanca | sp 1 | 1 |
| Blanca | sp 2 | 3 |
| Amarilla | sp 1 | 2 |

Quiero comprobar si hay una tendencia de cada especie hacia un color concreto, pero al hacer la tabla con

```
table(x = Database$Colour, y = Database$Species, fill = Database$N.Insects)
```

El resultado son varias tablas, una para cada Nº insectos, y yo necesito una sola tabla donde los valores sean una suma de todos los N insectos que se han encontrado en cada caso, algo así:

| Color | sp 1 | sp 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blanca | 1 | 3 |
| Amarilla | 2 | 0 |

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer:

```
library(tidyverse)

Database %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Species, values_from = N.Insects , values_fill = 0)
```

Pasar a columnas las Species, tomar los valores de N.insects y rellenar con 0

Una segunda opción:

```
library(reshape2)

Database %>% dcast(Colour ~ Species, value.var = "N.insects", sum)
```

Muy similar a lo anterior, en donde la formula considera pasar las Species a columnas distribuidas por Colour y especificar que la función que queremos aplicar es la suma

Answer (score 3):

`table()` no te va a funcionar en este caso, por que cuenta casos y lo que en realidad necesitas es en todo caso sumar los valor de `N.Insects`. En R base cuentas con [`xtabs()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/xtabs):

```
xtabs(N.Insects ~ Colour + Species, Database)

          Species
Colour     sp1 sp2
  Amarilla   2   0
  Blanca     1   3
```